# Jquery mobile, gap appearing when using fixed header and responsive panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I use the responsive panel on most of my pages but without a fixed header toolbar, as soon as i add data-position="fixed" to the header, it makes a gap when the panel is opened, like below: [image]

My markup is:

Header:

```
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" class="ui-transparent"></div>
```

Panel:

```
 <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-position="right"  data-display="push" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a" id="c_menu_recipe"></div>
```

NOTE: without fixed toolbar header, the gap is not there. Any tips?

Comment: Do you have a live demo?

Comment: provide your code in fiddle? what you done